# Conditional statements in Applescript?

Tags: applescript, midi

I am a complete neophyte with Applescript.  I am using Midipipe, and trying to set up some conditionals to alter Midi note numbers.

I have two Midi inputs and basically I just need a series of:

If (input one == (a program change variable)){
    input two + 1}
else
    blah blah blah...

I need to know how to format it and compile it to run in Midipipe so that it outputs the condition.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic statements for conditionals in AppleScript are:

```
if variable = value then
    -- do something
else if variable = othervalue then
    -- do something
else 
    -- do something
end if
```

***obs: "--" are  comments lines***